# A chain rule for weak time derivatives in Bochner space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in W(0,T)$ where
$$W(0,T) := \{ v \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(\Omega)) : v' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))\}$$
where $v'$ refers to the weak temporal derivative and $\Omega$ is a bounded and smooth domain.

Suppose that $G(t,\cdot)\colon \Omega \to \Omega$ is a smooth diffeomorphism for each $t$ with $t \mapsto G(t,x)$ also smooth for each $x$.

Consider the function
$$v(t,x) := u(t,G(t,x)).$$
I want to know if $v \in W(0,T)$ too. In particular the existence of $v'$ is hard to show because of the time dependence in $G$. One could approximate $u$ by smooth functions $u_n$ and derive
$$\frac{d}{dt}u_n(t,G(t,x)) = u_n'(t, G(t,x)) + \nabla u_n(t, G(t,x))\cdot G'(t,x)$$
but passing to the limit in the sense of weak derivatives requires certain conditions for fixed a.e. $x$ (eg. integrability in time), which don't appear to be true.

Comment: You yourself suggest a solution. Define $G$ such as it makes the derivative sufficiently wrong. You have a lot of space for that: $L^2$, $H^1=W^{1,2}$, non-compact (0,T), non-compact $\Omega$, not well specified ``smoothness'' of $G$, ... With the present formulation of the question, you may well succeed with $\Omega=(0,1)$, $u(t,x)=x$.